# Sequence of polynomials (Q2)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials

Define $P_0(x) = 0$ and for $n > 0, \ P_n(x) = (x \ + \ P_{n-1}^2(x)) / 2$ and $Q_n(x) = P_n(x) - P_{n-1}(x)$.  Are all the coefficients of the polynomials $Q_n(x)$ nonnegative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** Shortened according to a comment by Richard Hevener.

Let $\mathcal S$ be the set of polynomials with nonnegative coefficients.
Then by looking at how the coefficients of sums and products are obtained we observe the following simple

> **Lemma.** The set $\mathcal S$ is closed under addition and multiplication, i.e. $f,g\in\mathcal S$ implies $f+g,f\cdot g\in\mathcal S$.

Clearly, $P_0=0\in\mathcal S$ and by the lemma and the recursion formula for $P_n$, we have $P_n\in\mathcal S$ for all $n\ge 0$ by induction on $n$.
Now
$$\begin{align}Q_{n+1} &= P_{n+1}-P_n\\
&=\frac12(x+P_{n}^2)-\frac12(x+P_{n-1}^2)
\\&=\frac12(P_n+P_{n-1})(P_{n}-P_{n-1})\\
&=\frac12(P_n+P_{n-1})Q_n,\end{align}$$
hence $Q_{n+1}\in\mathcal S$ if $Q_n\in\mathcal S$ and $n\ge1$.
Thus the claim follows by induction for all $n\ge1$ because $Q_1=P_1\in\mathcal S$.

Comment: It is clear that $P_n$ is in $S$. The result then follows immediately from the representation $Q_{n+1} = (P_n + P_{n-1}) Q_n / 2$.

Comment: D'oh, why did I not see $P_n\ni\mathcal S$ right away? I was afraid, I'd need more explicit info about $P_n$ ...